# Bash date/time arithmetic

Tags: bash, date, time, sleep, suspend

I have a little Bash script which suspends the computer after a given number of minutes.  However, I'd like to extend it to tell me what the time will be when it will be suspended, so I can get a rough idea of how long time I have left so to speak.

```
#!/bin/sh
let SECS=$1*60
echo "Sleeping for" $1 "minutes, which is" $SECS "seconds."
sleep $SECS &&
pm-suspend
```

The only argument to the script will be how many minutes from now the computer should be suspended.  All I want to add to this script is basically an `echo` saying e.g. "Sleeping until HH:nn:ss!".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found out how.

```
echo "The computer will be suspended at" $(date --date "now $1 minutes")
```

Comment: admit it; you just asked this question so you could answer it and get the "self-learner" badge. :-)

Comment: Haha, no, seriously.  I think I already have that badge anyways?  No, I didn't.  No, but I just didn't think it was this easy.

Comment: The first pair of quotes is superfluous

Comment: Shorter: `date --date "$1 minutes" +'The computer will be suspended at %c'`

Answer (score 3):

On BSD-derived systems, you'd use

```
date -r $(( $(date "+%s") + $1 * 60 ))
```

i.e. get the current date in seconds, add the number of minutes, and feed it back to date.
Yeah, it's slightly less elegant.

Comment: @Chris I think formatting screwed you up there... there's no ending `

Comment: deleted my back-ticks comment since it's part of an answer below

Comment: more interesting to me is the use of the $ syntax to execute the date function instead of single back quotes.

Answer (score 1):

on linux

```
SECS=`date "+$s"`
SECS=$(( SECS + $1 * 60 ))
date --date $SECS
```

Comment: I think formatting screwed you up there... there's no ending `

Comment: I added backslashes to escape the backticks. fixed.